# How to integrate librePlan inside another application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, zk, libreplan

I am new to Libreplan, I have successfully build libreplan.war file and deployed it on tomcat6 on my windows machine. I need to integrate it inside my web application using iframe. When I am trying to access below URL, it redirects to login page because of spring security intercept-url. -

```
/libreplan-webapp/planner/index.zul;order=ORDER0003
```

Problem: I need to access the above url bypassing the login screen, may be with admin user credentials. As User already logged in to my web-application so we can't ask to login once again to access particular tab.

I have tried the below mentioned scenarios:

- creating Dummy context and setting it with SecurityContext manually.
- bypassing spring security filter be extending my own filter to create admin authenticatin and setting it to security context.
- changing intercept-url access to ISAUTHENTICATEDANONYMOUSLY.

I was thinking to implement either OAuth token or SSO(Single sign on) but not sure whether it will work or not.

Please suggest me on how to approach this, if the above mentioned scenarios will work (I am making some mistakes when implementing it) or do I need to approach differently.

Thanks in advance.